# Using an optimal transport map on new samples from same source distribution

Tags: distributions, function

I am trying to compute an optimal transport map from $p = U[0,1]^2$ to some 2D distribution $q$ given by an image, where pixel intensities represent unnormalized probabilities. My goal is to build a smooth map on a finite set of samples $(x_i,y_i) \sim (p,q)$ so that I can use it on unseen data $z_i \sim p$ later on. I can already sample $q$ via marginal/conditional inverse CDF transform, but I am seeking an OT solution to avoid discontinuities as much as possible.

How do I construct such a map and how can I use it transport new data points? I initially thought of densely sampling $p$ on a grid, computing the OT map towards $q$ and then interpolating the barycenters of the resulting Delaunay triangulation to map new points, but this seems rather involved. I've played around with [POT](https://pythonot.github.io/) which provides many routines to compute OT solutions but I feel like I'm not understanding 100% what I'm doing.

I know very little about OT so I don't have a good intuition on how I should proceed. My problem shares similarities with domain adaptation, except in my case the training and test distributions are the same.

Comment: Can you tell us  some context of this, where does this problem arise?

Comment: I'm trying to build an OT plan to map uniform 2D points to the distribution of an emitter given by an environment map in the context of Monte Carlo rendering. The classical approach uses marginal sampling but destroys stratification which is key to reducing variance, so I was wondering if using a smoother map could help. I have implemented the Delaunay approach and it seems to work well, but I have not found any prior work on this.